# Alternative to xmllint to check xml validity

Tags: linux, software-rec, xml

Sometimes, I have to check the validity of some big xml files against a xsd file.
The biggest xml file I received had a size close to 1.5GB.
`xmllint` took all my RAM and almost all the swap space, for a total memory usage of 18GB.
Consequently, the validation process lasted for 24 hours.

My question: Is there an alternative to `xmllint --schema` that consumes less memory, perhaps making use of some streaming features instead of loading the file to memory?

Comment: was that using the xmllint --stream option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did not test these validators, but from the top of my mind / little search:

1. [XMLStarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net) - can be used for other things as well
2. [`msv`](http://java.net/projects/msv) -  Sun multi schema validator
3. [`HaXML`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaXml) - haskell xml tools contains command line utilities (one is a validator)
4. `xsltproc` should also verify documents at startup

There are plenty more option as most utilities will automatically validate the xml document, like e.g. `xsltproc`.

Answer (score 1):

In my Linux system's package library I found xmlcopyeditor. I used it to to check an XML file as well as to edit it.
The man page claims it does "DTD/XML Schema/RELAX NG validation, XSLT, XPath, pretty-printing, syntax highlighting, folding, tag completion/locking, a spelling/style  check  and,  on Windows, lossless import/export of Microsoft Word documents." but I really haven't tested how well it it doe any of that.
I do know that pretty-printing didn't work until the start and end tags matched properly.
http://xml-copy-editor.sourceforge.net/